# ActionView::Template::Error (missing required :bucket option)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am receiving this error on heroku logs. I am now receiving this error after creating a new bucket on amazon s3 and adding my keys. I also added my keys/bucket name to heroku, as seen here:

```
=== benjaminsunderland Config Vars
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:        my_access_key
AWS_BUCKET:               mypinterestingapp
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:    my_secret_key
DATABASE_URL:             my_database_url
LANG:                     en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:                 production
RAILS_ENV:                production
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT:      enabled
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE:          my_secret_key_base
```

And also in enviroments/production.rb in my rails app

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['mypinterestingapp'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

my error in heroku logs:

```
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544099+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537] ActionView::Template::Error (missing required :bucket option):
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544249+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537]     15:   <tbody>
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544275+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537]     16:     <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544676+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537]     17:       <tr>
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544707+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537]     18:         <td><%= image_tag pin.image.url %></td>
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544734+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537]     19:         <td><%= pin.description %></td>
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544764+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537]     20:         <td><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></td>
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544790+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537]     21:         <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin %></td>
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544818+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537]   
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544854+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537] app/views/pins/index.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_pins_index_html_erb___1097567776692289569_70248207788000'
2016-11-09T19:10:32.544884+00:00 app[web.1]: [6df3c971-b288-4b7e-893e-dcea2f2ef537] app/views/pins/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_pins_index_html_erb___1097567776692289569_70248207788000'
```

What have I done wrong as heroku is coming up with this error, not the rails app. Do I have a typo? You can see that I named the AWS_BUCKET as exactly the same in my production.rb.

Comment: did you set `ENV['mypinterestingapp']` on HEROKU?

Comment: do you mean the 'heroku config' listed at the top of my post? Also, on the Heroku website in my config variables, my AWS_BUCKET is named correctly 'mypinterestingapp', if that is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Right now you're looking for an `ENV` variable called `'mypinterestingapp'` when you should be looking for `ENV['AWS_BUCKET']`, which doesn't exist.

Also, I replaced your actual credentials in the code sample above with some generic placeholders. Never a good idea to post actual credentials in a SO question ;)

Comment: My pleasure @Benjamints. Be careful with them AWS creds. You might even consider swapping out the keys since someone could have copied them before I edited them out.